# Not finding substring in a group regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a substring that looks like `"3/4"` (any number 0-9 for the numerator and denominator). However,  the text that I am trying to parse may contain only a `"/4"` if its 1/4. In those cases, I don't care about the `"/"` and only want the denominator. My current regular expression is `"[0-9?\\/0-9]"` but it returns `'3/4'` one by one, when I wanted it grouped instead.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the pipe to create an or:

```
 ([0-9]\/[0-9])|\/([0-9])
```

The downside of this approach though would be that you'd need to validate if group 1 or 2 returned a match... so if you had a full fraction you'd get a result in the first group, if you matched a denominator, the denominator would show up in the second group.

Might make more sense to:

```
([0-9]*\/[0-9])
```

And then check the length of each match back, and strip out the '/' if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
[0-9?\/0-9]
```

is a character class that matches a single digit, question mark, or slash. You want this:

```
[0-9]?\/[0-9]
```

or this:

```
\d?\/\d
```

Answer (score 0):

use a capture group via the `( )` operator

```
[0-9]?\/([0-9])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
"([0-9]*\\?[0-9]+)"
```